# Express amazement at the news, what news or such news! which is right?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrases, what, such

So I receive a piece of info instead of saying "no sh*t, Sherlock", I want to express amazement at the news in a sarcastic, biblical friendly way, e.g. *what news!* or *such news!* but those just sound weird and off.

Any help please?

Comment: Any expression of surprise could be said sarcastically.  In fact, some older phrases only seem to be used sarcastically, e.g. "you don't say", "who would have thought", "well I never", "is that a fact"

Comment: "You amaze me!" "Fancy that!"